# view highest-voted answers by a tag

Tags: support

Is it possible to view the highest-voted answers of all questions by a tag?

I know that this is already possible for questions but I can't find such a feature for answers. Have I overseen it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yup. Search for `[tag] is:answer` and sort by `votes` :)

Comment: Cool. That is what I searched for.